# Can't require ruby gsl on Alpine Linux

Tags: ruby, docker, gsl, alpine-linux

I am running alpine in a docker image and running ruby code. This successfully installs all packages but fails when I try require gsl.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

RUN apk upgrade --update \
    && apk add libatomic readline readline-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev \
        libxslt libxslt-dev zlib-dev zlib ruby yaml \
        yaml-dev libffi-dev build-base git nodejs \
        ruby-io-console ruby-irb ruby-json ruby-rake \
        make gsl gsl-dev \
        gcc g++ libffi-dev ruby-dev tzdata

RUN gsl-config --cflags
RUN gem install --no-document nmatrix gsl
ADD scripts/gsl-test.rb test.rb
RUN ruby test.rb
```

The test file is:

```
require 'gsl'
```

Running docker build . produces the following output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    20 MB
Step 0 : FROM alpine:3.4
 ---> ad84c222f6a3
Step 1 : RUN apk upgrade --update     && apk add libatomic readline readline-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev         libxslt libxslt-dev zlib-dev zlib ruby yaml         yaml-dev libffi-dev build-base git nodejs         ruby-io-console ruby-irb ruby-json ruby-rake         make gsl gsl-dev         gcc g++ libffi-dev ruby-dev tzdata
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b7f66d6f2bd7
Step 2 : RUN gsl-config --cflags
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b5acc8868a74
Step 3 : RUN gem install --no-document nmatrix gsl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2623683a706e
Step 4 : ADD scripts/gsl-test.rb test.rb
 ---> e4388f952198
Removing intermediate container 743340a3be60
Step 5 : RUN ruby test.rb
 ---> Running in c53a34ece153
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': Error relocating /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gsl-2.1.0.1/lib/gsl_native.so: gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_jac: symbol not found - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gsl-2.1.0.1/lib/gsl_native.so (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.6.8/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:9:in `require_with_backports'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/gsl-2.1.0.1/lib/gsl.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
The command '/bin/sh -c ruby test.rb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is you're running gsl version 1.16 and then running the latest gsl gem (2.1.0.1). If you force the gem install to match the gsl version:

```
gem install --no-document gsl -v 1.16.0.6
```

It should work splendidly.